# What is an example of "array destructuring" via "assignment pattern" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

This [MDN documentation on destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#binding_and_assignment) says that "for both **object** and **array** destructuring, there are two kinds of destructuring patterns: **binding pattern** and **assignment pattern**".  Therefore, there should be four types of destructuring syntax:

- **Type 1**: object destructuring via binding pattern
- **Type 2**: array destructuring via binding pattern
- **Type 3**: object destructuring via assignment pattern
- **Type 4**: array destructuring via assignment pattern

I have read through the MDN documentation page many times, and the page seems to have provided examples only for the first 3 types.  Googling doesn't seem to help either.

What would be an example of Type 4?

Thanks!

#### Update 1:

For Type 3, MDN provided this example:

```js
// This assigns a to numbers[0] , and b to number[1] 
({ a: numbers[0], b: numbers[1] } = obj);
```

What would be an equivalent example for Type 4?  Thanks!

Comment: The `Swapping variables` example shows Type 4.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MDN should have explained Type 4 with a clearer and simpler example.  Here you go:

```js
const source = [1, 2, 3];
const target = [4, 5];

[target[0], target[1]] = source; // target = [1, 2]
```

Also, JavaScript arrays are just objects with indexed properties, so the above can also be written as the Type 3 format below:

```js
({ 0: target[0], 1: target[1] } = source);
```

Comment: "*JavaScript arrays are just objects with indexed properties*" - true, but array destructuring syntax not only works with arrays but with any iterable

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of each of the four types you listed:

- Type 1: Object destructuring via binding pattern

  ```js
  const person = {
    name: 'Alice',
    age: 30,
  };

  const { name, age } = person;
  ```
- Type 2: Array destructuring via binding pattern

  ```js
  const rgb = [255, 200, 100];

  const [red, green, blue] = rgb;
  ```
- Type 3: Object destructuring via assignment pattern

  ```js
  const person = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 25,
  };

  let name, age;
  ({ name, age } = person);
  ```
- Type 4: Array destructuring via assignment pattern

  ```js
  const rgb = [255, 200, 100];

  let red, green, blue;
  [red, green, blue] = rgb;
  ```
- Advanced example for type 4:

  ```js
  const obj = {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  };

  let a, b;

  // This assigns a to obj.numbers[0], and b to obj.numbers[1]
  [a, b] = obj.numbers;
  ```

To surgically and individually extract each indexed element of an array value using array destructuring with the assignment pattern, do the following:

```js
const obj = {
  numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
};

let a, c, e;

// This assigns obj.numbers[0] to a, obj.numbers[2] to c, and obj.numbers[4] to c
([a, , c, , e] = obj.numbers);
```

In this example, we're destructuring the `numbers` array from the `obj` object and assigning its 1st, 3rd, and 5th elements to the variables `a`, `c`, and `e` respectively. We use elisions between the commas to skip the elements we don't want to extract.

Comment: Thanks for providing examples for Type 3 and Type 4.  Would you be able to provide a more complete example?  For Type 3, the MDN example is this: ({ a: numbers[0], b: numbers[1] } = obj);  /* This assigns a to numbers[0] , and b to number[1] */.  What would be the equivalent example for Type 4?  Thanks!

Comment: @Emma a more advanced example has been added, as requested.

Comment: Another example has been provided that's as close as possible to what you're asking @Emma

Comment: "*a single variable of type Array.prototype*" - that doesn't make any sense

Comment: I used the exact wording the OP requested @Bergi if you'd say it a different way, feel free to make a suggestion